# IK Bone detaches / disconnects / separates during grab movement

Tags: rigging

Is this a normal result for grabbing the IK bone after connecting an IK to a parent bone? If not, how do I keep the IK bone connected to the forearm bone via the wrist knob?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: did u try to check "connected"? this checkbox ensures that the "connected" bone will be directly attached to its parented bone

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I never knew there was a connected checkbox in the Bone Properties->Relation dropdown. Selecting the IK bone it's greyed out, shift selecting both bones it's still greyed out. What's the trick?

Comment: you have to be in edit mode to do this - and it's "normal" to don't see things who exist and to learn everyday - i make the same experience everyday with Blender ;)

Comment: Thanks again @Chris I tried that the other day but in order to connect it in edit mode I have to set the parent and then when I connect it, the ik feature stops functioning. (No bones rotate except the IK bone)